# Is it ok to dynamically change function?

Tags: javascript, function, dynamic

I have:

```
var diagram = {
  init: function(name) {
    this._name = name;
  },

  update: function(params) {
    var selector = 'diagram_name_' + this._name;

    this.update = function(params) {
      app.updateBlock(selector, params);
    };

    this.updateDiagram(params);
  };

diagram.update(); // caches `selector`
diagram.update(); // uses cached `selector`
```

`diagram` object has method `update`. This method uses `selector` variable. First time calling `update()`, I cache this variable and change `update` method so next time I call it, this method will use cached `selector`.

I would like to know if this approach is ok in terms of performance (and if it is ok at all). Any ideas?

P.S.

I know I can create private field `_selector` and execute `this._selector = 'diagram_name_' + name` during `init` method, but this approach creates private field that is used by one method only, does not feel right.

Comment: It will be perfectly fine performance wise, but I don't know if it's best practice. I feel it would be confusing (for someone else) if the function was to do two different things at two different times.

Comment: This is an interesting question but as phrased, it might end up closed for being too opinion-based. Can you rephrase it, maybe along the lines "How can I avoid having this function update itself?". You can ask the opinion-based questions (should I leave it as self-updating?) if the title isn't so inviting of opinion-based answers.

Comment: "but this approach creates private field that is used by one method only, does not feel right" - I would say it's more "right" than changing a function on the fly. All down to personal preference though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's ok. It's called [Self-Defining Functions](http://www.ricfrank.net/2013/11/25/javascript-self-defining-functions-pattern/). Also the pattern was described in the awesome book "JavaScript Patterns" by Stoyan Stefanov.

Answer (score 1):

A better way might be to cache selector on the object:

```
this._selector || (this._selector = "value");
```

That way, there's less magic and you still have access to all of the old data instead of making it disappear.

What you also might want to checkout is the technique known as [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), something that's been solved many times (to avoid having to do it yourself).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to worry about performance and the `update` method will also behave in the expected way. So technically, this pattern will work.

However, I find it rather confusing. Of course, when it comes to code clarity, things are always a bit subjective, but here is what I would suggest:

**Method 1**

Separate the two cases completely and make sure that outside code calls `updateDiagram` before it calls `update`:

```
var diagram = {
    init: function(name) {
        this._name = name;
    },

    update: function(params) {
        var selector = 'diagram_name_' + this._name;
        app.updateBlock(selector, params);
    },

    updateDiagram: function(params) {
        //...
    }
};
```

**Method 2**

Use parameter to indicate which of the cases should be used:

```
var diagram = {
    init: function(name) {
        this._name = name;
        this._diagramUpToDate = false;
    },

    update: function(params) {
        if (this._diagramUpToDate) {
            var selector = 'diagram_name_' + this._name;
            app.updateBlock(selector, params);
        } else {
            this.updateDiagram(params);
        }
    },

    updateDiagram: function(params) {
        //...
        this.diagramUpToDate = true;
    }
};
```

Of course it is your choice what you use in the end. As I said, your approach also works fine and the only issue might be code clarity.